# Offset time with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that pulls results from two tables. The datetime is stored in one table and time offset in minutes (-300) is in the second table. Is it possible to retrieve already offset local time or do I need to do calculation with PHP?

```
SELECT
   t1.eventName, 
   t1.eventTime, 
   t2.offsetTime
WHERE id = 2
```

Event time is stored in the following format: **2015-11-05 02:04:01** 
and offset time: **-360**

If I go MySQL route, do I need to convert them to milliseconds first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do that calculation in a MySQL expresssion.

If `t2.offsetTime` is integer datatype representing a number of minutes, and `t1.eventTime` is datatype of DATETIME, TIMESTAMP or DATE... you can use an expression to add the offset (in minutes) to the datetime.

For example:

```
  t1.eventTime + INTERVAL t2.offsetTime MINUTE
```

Just use that expression in the SELECT list, for example:

```
SELECT t1.eventName
     , t1.eventTime + INTERVAL t2.offsetTime MINUTE AS offsetEventTime
     , t1.eventTime
     , t2.offsetTime
  FROM t1
  JOIN t2
    ON ...
```

---

If you prefer to use a function in the expression, MySQL provides the `DATE_ADD` function which performs the same...

```
 DATE_ADD(t1.eventTime, INTERVAL t2.offsetTime MINUTE)
```

---

(In place of `MINUTE`, you can use `DAY`, `HOUR`, `MONTH`, `SECOND`, et al.)

Answer (score 2):

There are [a load of different functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) you can use to achieve this like [`SUBTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime) & [`ADDTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime).

In your case it might be something like*:

```
SELECT ADDTIME(t1.eventTime, t2.offsetTime) as newTime
```

*You may need to use another function to convert `-300` into a format like `-00:05`.